# ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT - problem with google ads api

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api

I create the app which need to get data about keywords from google ads api. It looks like this

```
    public function planner()
    {
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
            ->fromFile(config_path('google_ads_php.ini'))
            ->build();
        $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
            ->fromFile(config_path('google_ads_php.ini'))
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            ->build();

        dd($this->runExample($googleAdsClient, "xxx"));
    }

    public function runExample(
        GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient,
        int $customerId
    ) {

        $keywordPlanIdeaServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getKeywordPlanIdeaServiceClient();
        $response = $keywordPlanIdeaServiceClient->generateKeywordHistoricalMetrics(
            [
                'customerId' => $customerId,
                'keywords' => ['mars cruise', 'cheap cruise', 'jupiter cruise'],
                'geo_target_constants' => [ResourceNames::forGeoTargetConstant(2840)],
                'language' => ResourceNames::forLanguageConstant(1000)
            ]
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

Problem is that all the time it returns me following error:
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuSkm.png)

Do you know what is wrong?
@Edit
I'm using testing version of api (testing app can be used by choosen users). I thought that I can add some scopes but I can't see keyword's scope https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes?hl=en. Where problem is?

@Edit

My scopes:
[image: my scopes]

Comment: Check access token permissions

Comment: I think so but which? I tryed use testing version of api

Comment: What scopes did you give your client, in its config?

Comment: I added screen to the post with my scopes. I think you wrote about configuration scopes in Google Platform?